# binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'web::json::object'

Tags: c++

I try to push a `web::json::value::object` into a `web::json::value::array`. But I got this failure information

> binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type
>   'web::json::object'

```cpp
void UserSettings::UpdateSettingsArray( web::json::array &settingsArray, web::json::array &templateArray, const bool& success )
{
  if( success )
  {
    for( const auto& t : templateArray )
    {
      auto temp = t.as_object();
      temp.erase( keyValue );
      temp[keySuccess] = web::json::value( true );
      settingsArray[settingsArray.size()] = web::json::value(temp);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    settingsArray[settingsArray.size()] = std::move( templateArray[0] );
  }
}
```

I hope I could push `temp` into `settingsArray`.

Comment: `web::json` -- This is not a standard C++ class or library?  What library is this?

Comment: Is this the Microsoft Rest SDK? Formerly known as Casablanca?

Comment: "I got this failure information..". What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using the Microsoft C++ Rest SDK https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk .

I watched the documentation, if I try to compile your code I get a different error (I am using the SDK 2.10.12.1), the error is still in

```
  settingsArray[settingsArray.size()] = web::json::value(temp);
```

and for me the compiler complains that there is no constructor of `value` that takes as input an `object`.

If I write

```
   settingsArray[settingsArray.size()] = temp;
```

I get the error you are having because there is no assignment operator for `value`that takes an `object`.

Regardless, the issue is

```
  auto temp = t.as_object();
```

you are converting the `web::json::value` to a `web::json::object`once you do it, you are stuck with it, because from the documentation I was unable to find a way to go from `web::json::object` to `web::json::value`

You could do something like:

```
   auto& temp = t.as_object();
```

modify `temp` and insert `t`, for example, but I do not like taking references to internals of instances, change the references and expect the "main" instance to change, it is not easy to reason about.

Luckily the documentation for `value`, https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1json_1_1value.html , tells us that you can use `erase` and `operator []` directly on `value` and this will modify the underlying `object`. The documentation does not say (as far as I can see) what happens if you use these operators on a `value` that is not an `object`, so you might want to do something like this

```
void UpdateSettingsArray(web::json::array& settingsArray, web::json::array& templateArray, const bool& success)
{

    if (success)
    {
        for (web::json::value t : templateArray)
        {
            if (!t.is_object())
                //do something, for example, throw your own exception
                throw std::exception{};

            t.erase(keyValue);
            t[keySuccess] = web::json::value(true);
            settingsArray[settingsArray.size()] = t;
        }
    } else {
        settingsArray[settingsArray.size()] = std::move(templateArray[0]);
    }
}
```

For me this compiles, but I cannot say whether the runtime behavior is what you want.

Final note:

```
   settingsArray[settingsArray.size()]
```

From the code it looks like `operator[]` triggers a resize of the array if the index is out of bound, but I cannot find any explicit mention of the of this behavior in the documentation.